# Help with string replacement

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create a variable that performs a couple of different replacement rules.. for example if the variable name comes back with a space I replace it with a hyphen.  If it contains an ampersand then it removes it from the string.  Right now I have this :

```
$reg_ex_space = "[[:space:]]";
$replace_space_with = "-";
$reg_ex_amper = "[&amp;]";
$replace_amper_with = "";
$manLink1 = ereg_replace ($reg_ex_amper, $replace_amper_with, $manName);
$manLink2 = ereg_replace ($reg_ex_space, $replace_space_with, $manLink1);
```

and when I echo manLink2 from something that has an ampersand, say Tom & Jerry it will return Tom--Jerry.

Can someone please explain a more efficient/working way to write this ?

Comment: What would you prefer? `Tom-Jerry`? Couldn't you just switch the order of your replacements? (Also, [have you considered using `preg_replace`?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace `&amp;` with blank string (removing it) and convert spaces to `-`.

It will then condense multiple `-` together to one.

```
$str = str_replace(array('&amp;', ' '), array('', '-'), $str);

$str = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/Pc6VqIax).